# Does NSURLSession multiplex HTTP/2 requests from different sessions?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, ios9, http2

If an app creates two NSURLSession objects that request data from the same server (that supports HTTP/2), are the requests from both sessions multiplexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no.  The existence of certain settings in the session configuration that affect the actual connection behavior (pipelining, cellular access, and timeouts in particular) would make sharing a connection pool between sessions problematic at best.